# When Google Logging Library is called by Python, how can we define the location of the log file?

Tags: python, c++, glog

I am now calling a C++ library in Python with the help of [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This C++ library uses [Google Logging Library](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html) for logging message. I know that when I set up a C++ application that calls the library, I can easily control where the log file is located:

```
 #include <glog/logging.h>

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     // Initialize Google's logging library.
     google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

     // ...
     LOG(INFO) << "Found " << num_cookies << " cookies";
   }
```

However, now I am calling it from the Python codes. Then my question is how can I set up the log file so that the log information in the C++ library can be written to the defined log file. By the way, I have the source code of the C++ library, and I can compile it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://rawgit.com/google/glog/v0.3.5/doc/glog.html), setting environment variable `GLOG_log_dir` should work:

```
GLOG_log_dir='/my/log/dir/' python my_code.py
```

According to the [code](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/v0.3.5/src/logging.cc#L154), setting environment variable `GOOGLE_LOG_DIR` may also work.